# Firebase account queries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna know that if my app was deleted by Google from play store then what happens to my app's database in firebase .
Will my app is also deleted from firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your database will remain on `Firebase servers`. They only delete your app the from `Google Play`. This means that your app won't be able to be instaled by any other users. This doesn't mean that the database will be deleted.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer